# Error when using CMake and ninja to install opencv to be used in embarcadero C++ builder 10.3

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, c++builder, ninja

I want to use opencv in embarcadero C++ builder 10.3 and online I found out you need to use CMake to make that happen. I downloaded opencv 3.4.16 from the opencv site and use the commands given [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder).
The specifications of the software I use:

- CMake 3.19.4
- Ninja 1.11.1
- C++ builder 10.3
- Classic compiler in embarcadero
- 32 bit in embarcadero
- opencv 3.4.16

I follow those steps and use the command to configure and generate the files. After running that command I use the ninja command to try and finish the CMake but I get an error at around 70 of 1400:

```
C:\opencv-3.4.16\build>ninja
[1/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzclose.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\gzclose.c:
[2/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\adler32.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\adler32.c:
[3/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzlib.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\gzlib.c:
[4/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzwrite.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\gzwrite.c:
[5/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\crc32.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\crc32.c:
[6/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzread.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\gzread.c:
[7/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\compress.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\compress.c:
[8/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\deflate.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\deflate.c:
[9/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\zutil.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\zutil.c:
[10/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\inftrees.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\inftrees.c:
[11/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\uncompr.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\uncompr.c:
[12/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\inffast.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\inffast.c:
[13/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\infback.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\infback.c:
[14/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\trees.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:
[15/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\inflate.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\zlib\inflate.c:
[16/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcapimin.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcapimin.c:
[17/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcapistd.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcapistd.c:
[18/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jccoefct.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jccoefct.c:
[19/1345] Linking C static library 3rdparty\lib\zlibd.lib
TLIB 7.0 Copyright (c) 1987-2019 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
[20/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcdctmgr.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcdctmgr.c:
[21/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcicc.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcicc.c:
[22/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jccolor.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jccolor.c:
[23/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcmainct.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcmainct.c:
[24/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcinit.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcinit.c:
[25/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcmaster.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcmaster.c:
[26/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcmarker.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcmarker.c:
[27/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcomapi.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcomapi.c:
[28/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcsample.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcsample.c:
[29/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcprepct.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcprepct.c:
[30/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcparam.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcparam.c:
[31/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jctrans.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jctrans.c:
[32/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcphuff.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcphuff.c:
[33/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdapimin.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdapimin.c:
[34/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdatadst.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdatadst.c:
[35/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdatasrc.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdatasrc.c:
[36/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdcoefct.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdcoefct.c:
[37/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jchuff.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jchuff.c:
[38/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdapistd.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdapistd.c:
[39/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jddctmgr.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jddctmgr.c:
[40/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdicc.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdicc.c:
[41/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdinput.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdinput.c:
[42/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdcolor.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdcolor.c:
[43/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdhuff.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdhuff.c:
[44/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdmainct.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdmainct.c:
[45/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdmaster.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdmaster.c:
[46/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdmarker.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdmarker.c:
[47/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdphuff.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdphuff.c:
[48/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdpostct.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdpostct.c:
[49/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jfdctflt.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jfdctflt.c:
[50/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdsample.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdsample.c:
[51/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jerror.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jerror.c:
[52/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jfdctfst.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jfdctfst.c:
[53/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdmerge.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdmerge.c:
[54/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdtrans.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdtrans.c:
[55/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jidctflt.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jidctflt.c:
[56/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jfdctint.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jfdctint.c:
[57/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jidctfst.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jidctfst.c:
[58/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jutils.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jutils.c:
[59/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jquant1.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jquant1.c:
[60/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jidctred.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jidctred.c:
[61/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jquant2.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jquant2.c:
[62/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jaricom.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jaricom.c:
[63/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jmemnobs.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jmemnobs.c:
[64/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jidctint.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jidctint.c:
[65/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jmemmgr.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jmemmgr.c:
[66/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jdarith.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jdarith.c:
[67/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jsimd_none.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jsimd_none.c:
[68/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\CMakeFiles\libjpeg-turbo.dir\src\jcarith.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jcarith.c:
[69/1345] Linking C static library 3rdparty\lib\libjpeg-turbod.lib
TLIB 7.0 Copyright (c) 1987-2019 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: duplicate file 'libjpeg' in list, not added!
Warning: 'libjpeg' not found in library
Warning: '3rdparty\libjpeg.obj' file not found
Warning: 'jcapimin.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcapistd.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jccoefct.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jccolor.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcdctmgr.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jchuff.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcicc.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcinit.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcmainct.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcmarker.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcmaster.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcomapi.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcparam.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcphuff.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcprepct.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcsample.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jctrans.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdapimin.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdapistd.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdatadst.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdatasrc.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdcoefct.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdcolor.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jddctmgr.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdhuff.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdicc.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdinput.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdmainct.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdmarker.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdmaster.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdmerge.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdphuff.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdpostct.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdsample.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdtrans.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jerror.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jfdctflt.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jfdctfst.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jfdctint.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jidctflt.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jidctfst.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jidctint.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jidctred.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jquant1.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jquant2.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jutils.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jmemmgr.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jmemnobs.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jaricom.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jcarith.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jdarith.c' not found in library
Warning: 'jsimd_none.c' not found in library
[70/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_close.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_close.c:
[71/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_codec.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_codec.c:
[72/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_color.c.obj
FAILED: 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_color.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\EMBARC~1\Studio\20.0\bin\bcc32x.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -I3rdparty\zlib -I..\3rdparty\zlib -I3rdparty\libtiff -I..\3rdparty\libtiff -I. -I3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo -I..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\crtl" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\sdk" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\rtl" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64" -tM   -fsigned-char  -O0 -g -o3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_color.c.obj -c ..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_color.c
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_color.c:
In file included from ..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_color.c:38:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\crtl\math.h:723:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\ymath.h:4:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\yvals.h:10:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\xkeycheck.h:44:5: error: keyword defined before including C standard header
   #error keyword defined before including C standard header
    ^
1 error generated.
[73/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_aux.c.obj
FAILED: 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_aux.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\EMBARC~1\Studio\20.0\bin\bcc32x.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -I3rdparty\zlib -I..\3rdparty\zlib -I3rdparty\libtiff -I..\3rdparty\libtiff -I. -I3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo -I..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\crtl" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\sdk" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\rtl" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64" -tM   -fsigned-char  -O0 -g -o3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_aux.c.obj -c ..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_aux.c
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_aux.c:
In file included from ..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_aux.c:32:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\crtl\math.h:723:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\ymath.h:4:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\yvals.h:10:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\xkeycheck.h:44:5: error: keyword defined before including C standard header
   #error keyword defined before including C standard header
    ^
1 error generated.
[74/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_compress.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_compress.c:
[75/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_dirinfo.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_dirinfo.c:
[76/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_dir.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_dir.c:
[77/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_dumpmode.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_dumpmode.c:
[78/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_dirwrite.c.obj
FAILED: 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_dirwrite.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\EMBARC~1\Studio\20.0\bin\bcc32x.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -I3rdparty\zlib -I..\3rdparty\zlib -I3rdparty\libtiff -I..\3rdparty\libtiff -I. -I3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo -I..\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\crtl" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\sdk" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\rtl" -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64" -tM   -fsigned-char  -O0 -g -o3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_dirwrite.c.obj -c ..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_dirwrite.c
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_dirwrite.c:
In file included from ..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_dirwrite.c:32:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\crtl\math.h:723:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\ymath.h:4:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\yvals.h:10:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\dinkumware64\xkeycheck.h:44:5: error: keyword defined before including C standard header
   #error keyword defined before including C standard header
    ^
1 error generated.
[79/1345] Building C object 3rdparty\libtiff\CMakeFiles\libtiff.dir\tif_dirread.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
..\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_dirread.c:
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Does anyone know how I can use opencv in embarcadero C++ builder 10.3

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/cmake-error-trying-to-add-opencv-to-embarcadero-c-builder-10-3/13160

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz seem to be a different issue from what I see.

Comment: hence "related", not "crosspost". related because it's the same user name and the situation is OpenCV with C++ Builder